# Passport Sessions not getting destroyed on browser close

Tags: node.js, session, azure, couchbase, passport.js

I have a Node.js server and I am using passport for session management. Planning on using it to implement remember me functionality for the server soon. But I have a problem where the normal sessions are basically acting as a remember me. Aka the session cookie `connect.sid` is not getting destroyed on browser close which I believe is not the correct behavior. I am using [connect-bluesky](https://github.com/pofallon/connect-bluesky) as the session store (uses azure tables) and couchbase for storing default session information for future use.

Relevant code:

Server.js

```
app.configure(function()
{
    app.use(express.logger('dev')); // log every request to the console
    
    // set up our express application
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.json())
    .use(express.urlencoded());

    app.use(express.static(__dirname));

    var db = new couchbase.Connection({host: 'http://localhost:8091', bucket: 'default'}, function (err){
        
        console.log("In cb connect");
        console.log(err);

    });

    app.use(express.session({secret: 'SECRET', 
        store: new BlueskyStore({
          account: 'ACCOUNT',
          key: 'KEY',
          table: 'sessionsTable',
          cookie: { path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: null }
        })
    }));

    app.engine('html', engines.ejs);
    //app.set('views', __dirname+'/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'html');

    var data = fs.readFileSync( __dirname+"/"+process.argv['2'],'utf8');
    GLOBAL.infoJSON = JSON.parse(data);
    
    require('./config/passport')(passport, infoJSON);
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
    app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

    app.use(app.router);

});
```

Routes.js

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    res.redirect('/');
}

app.post('/login2', passport.authenticate('local-login'),
  function(req, res) 
  {
    var input = "irrelevant input string";

    var loginInfo = {
        input : input,
        userName : req.user.id,
        repoId : req.user.repoId
    }

    edgeMod.loginWF(loginInfo, req, res, function (req, res, result)
    {
        res.write(result);
        res.end();
    });
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res)
{
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

passport.js

```
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {

        db.set(user.id, user, function(err, result) {
            done(null, JSON.stringify(user));
        });
        
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(json, done) 
    {      
        var user = JSON.parse(json);        
        db.get(user.id, function(err, result) 
        {
            if (result)
            {
                
                done(null, result.value);
            }
            else
            {
                done(new Error("Bad JSON string in session"), null);
            }
        });
       
    });

  passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true 
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) 
    { 
        ---login checks---
        return done(null, serializeJson);
            
        });

    }));
```

How do I ensure sessions get destroyed on browser close? Any tips for doing this as its my 1st time doing something like this?

EDIT: It seems to be clearing the session on browser close in Firefox but not in chrome. Could this have something to do with chrome remembering pages on close?

Comment: `cookie: { path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: null }` should be an option of `express.session`, but you set it as an option of `BlueskyStore`.

Comment: I tried both and it did not make a difference. Also it seems to be working on Firefox like in my question but not on chrome (with continue on from close enabled.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having "Continue where you left off" ticked in chrome options seems to be the problem. Doesn't clear the session on browser close with this ticked.